# How can I select which multi-index axis splits the data in a groupby object across different subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I'm working with a `pandas.groupby` object to which I have applied a function as such:

```
x = data.groupby(['congruent', 'contrast']).apply(lambda s: s.mean())[['cresp1', 'cresp2']]
```

Output of `print x`:

```
                      cresp1    cresp2
congruent contrast                    
False     1.0       0.423077  0.442308
          2.0       0.537037  0.481481
          2.5       0.576923  0.634615
          3.0       0.568182  0.500000
          3.5       0.675000  0.750000
          4.0       0.687500  0.604167
          5.0       0.687500  0.875000
          10.0      0.869565  0.913043
True      1.0       0.568182  0.386364
          2.0       0.547619  0.500000
          2.5       0.522727  0.477273
          3.0       0.557692  0.634615
          3.5       0.571429  0.928571
          4.0       0.770833  0.937500
          5.0       0.791667  0.937500
          10.0      0.820000  0.920000
```

I would like to plot these data into two distinct subplots, one for all values where `congruent == False` and the other for all values where `congruent == True`.

I tried doing `x.plot(subplots=True)`, but this creates a subplot for each *column* (i.e. `cresp1` vs `cresp2`), which is **not** what I want:

[image]

How can I do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw it yourself:

```
import pylab as pl
import io
import pandas as pd

txt = """congruent contrast  cresp1    cresp2
False     1.0       0.423077  0.442308
          2.0       0.537037  0.481481
          2.5       0.576923  0.634615
          3.0       0.568182  0.500000
          3.5       0.675000  0.750000
          4.0       0.687500  0.604167
          5.0       0.687500  0.875000
          10.0      0.869565  0.913043
True      1.0       0.568182  0.386364
          2.0       0.547619  0.500000
          2.5       0.522727  0.477273
          3.0       0.557692  0.634615
          3.5       0.571429  0.928571
          4.0       0.770833  0.937500
          5.0       0.791667  0.937500
          10.0      0.820000  0.920000"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True).ffill()
df = df.set_index(["congruent","contrast"])
levels = df.index.levels[0]
fig, axes = pl.subplots(len(levels))

for level, ax in zip(levels, axes):
    df.loc[level].plot(ax=ax, title=str(level))
```

output:

[image]

Comment: I really like this HYRY's solution. Is there a good way to use it to place 4 Graphs on an 2x2 grid?

Comment: While using in IPython or JupyterNotebook if you face string vs binary error then you can encode your string by using .encode()