# Subplot multiindex data by level

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, subplot

This is my multiindex data.

```
Month   Hour    Hi
1       9       84.39
       10       380.41
       11       539.06
       12       588.70
       13       570.62
       14       507.42
       15       340.42
       16       88.91
2       8       69.31
        9       285.13
       10       474.95
       11       564.42
       12       600.11
       13       614.36
       14       539.79
       15       443.93
       16       251.57
       17       70.51
```

I want to make subplot where each subplot represent the Month. x axis is hour, y axis is Hi of the respective month.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059912/how-can-i-select-which-multi-index-axis-splits-the-data-in-a-groupby-object-acro) gives a beautiful approach as follow:

```
levels = df.index.levels[0]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(levels), figsize=(3, 25))

for level, ax in zip(levels, axes):
    df.loc[level].plot(ax=ax, title=str(level))
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

I want to make 1x2 subplot instead of vertically arranged as above. Later, with larger data, I want to make 3x4 subplot or even larger dimension.
How to do it?

Comment: `fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(levels), figsize=(3, 25))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in `pandas`

```
df.Hi.unstack(0).fillna(0).plot(kind='line',subplots=True, layout=(1,2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Pass the rows and columns arguments to `plt.subplots`

```
levels = df.index.levels[0]
#         Number of rows v
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(levels), figsize=(6, 3))

for level, ax in zip(levels, axes):
    df.loc[level].plot(ax=ax, title=str(level))
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]